# How can I apply timeout function to LMAX Disruptor Queue?

Tags: timeout, queue, disruptor-pattern

To developers/users of LMAX Disruptor http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/ :

My question:
Can anyone suggest an approach to how apply a timeout function to Disruptor e.g. using EventHandler?

Here is one scenario that came up in my line of work:

1. Outbox - messages sent to the Server over a network
2. Inbox - ACK messages received from the Server
3. ACK Handler - marks outbox messages as ACKed
4. Timeout Handler - marks outbox message as NACKed (much needed, but where can it fit into the Disruptor design?)

Is there anyone who share the same opinion? 
Or can anyone point out why it is unnecessary.
I hope the ensuing debate would be brief.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the timeout-handler would "fire" after a certain period of time when a message could not be delivered?

The way it works with disruptor is you have a ringbuffer for inbound and a ringbuffer for outbound messges... so email comes in, place it into the inbound ring buffer using an appropriate event. then process the message (i.e. decode, analye, log, store) and send it along to another sytem by placing it into the outbound ringbuffer... another handler takes the message and stores it into a database or sends it to another server using smtp... if a error / timeout etc. occurs, your create an event in the inbound ringbuffer signaling the error (NACK) and process this message. does that make sense?!?

Comment: Yes, a timeout EventHandler that gets invoked when any objects stays too long in ringbuffer.
The problem is that I don't see how EventHandler can be implement and registered to RingBuffer/Distruptor to support timeouts.
Only solution I can think is to customize my own EventProcessor.

Comment: Sorry for not replying soooo long. You would have to republish it a set number of times i.e. the number of retries for sending the email... or until time t has elapsed... so the thread always comes back to it.